# A virus that makes you stupid?

Tags: viruses

If somehow a virus that makes everybody who gets the virus have a IQ of about 60-70. How would the world react? I am mostly intrested in what would most likely happen the the people infected. The virus spreads by touch and whoever gets touched has a 15 percent chance of turning.

Comment: This seems an unanswerable question. I know what you want, but IQ is such a difficult subject. Will their understanding drop? Their knowledge? Their ability to plan? To think in 2D and 3D space for planning a house or tactics? Their ability to understand how someone climbed a wall and replicate it? IQ is to this day controversial and hard to define truly.

Comment: As the recent COVID pandemic has shown, "how would the world react to a virus" is a rather opinion based question. Please focus on a specific problem, answerable in a measurable way

Comment: I am convinced that there are at least seven different strains of this virus type at large on Earth right now. Everybody is just too stupid to notice.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica In hindsight, most of the reactions were very predictable and we already can see what specific factors were associated with specific reactions. The question does need clarifications, as Trioxidane mentions, and I would suggest adding more on the virus itself (a more detailed epidemiological model: incubation period, vectors, patient 0 location, etc.) and focusing on specific countries/cultures. This question lacks clarity and needs more focus, but it can be answered with facts and citations.

Comment: @Otkin In hindsight, everyone ignored the obvious exponentially growing crisis in front of them until the last possible moment and tried to argue that this was just anther swine flu. https://web.archive.org/web/20200211233714/https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/90254/is-it-still-possible-to-contain-the-coronavirus-outbreak Then the market crashed and suddenly everyone took it seriously.

Comment: This was what reddit looked like back when the cdc and WHO were antimask: https://i.imgur.com/wvTRciH.png Even though the powers that be knew a major crisis was coming, but they didn't let us know how bad it was: In January 24, The Senate Health Committee hosted an all-members briefing on the coronavirus. Afterwards, four US Senators were so spooked that they dumped all of their stock - https://www.vox.com/2020/3/20/21188144/senators-dumping-stock-as-market-tanks

Comment: @SurpriseDog My point is that all those reactions were predictable. This question can be answered using similar predictions.